# Want to disable the command based on canexecute

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, prism

I have a simple DelegateCommand from Telerik. I have a case,
I have a screen with a textbox and a button. Whenever I click save the button should be disabled and should not accept any clicks until the operation completes.

The implementation is as below,

```
 public DelegateCommand SaveRemarksCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveRemarksCommand = new DelegateCommand((r) =>
                {
                    CanSaveRemarks = false;
                    SaveRemarksCommand.InvalidateCanExecute();
                    SaveRemarks(null);
                },
                (result) =>
                {
                    return CanSaveRemarks;
                });

        }
    }
```

Here I am manipulating the CanSaveRemarks as false until the SaveRemarks executes.
The problem now is if I click multiple times fast on the button the button accepts multiple clicks saving duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally check the `CanSaveRemarks` property in your command handler.
This property is already available to you, so you don't need to introduce something else.

```
new DelegateCommand((r) =>
{
    if (!CanSaveRemarks)
    {
        return;
    }

    CanSaveRemarks = false;
    try
    {
        SaveRemarksCommand.InvalidateCanExecute();
        SaveRemarks(null);
    }
    finally
    {
        CanSaveRemarks = true;
    }
},
(result) =>
{
    return CanSaveRemarks;
});
```